# Prefix files with the current directory name using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have folders with images (*.png and *.jpg)

```
>C:\Directory\Folder1
01.png
02.png
03.jpg
04.jpg
05.png
```

And I want to rename all the files like this using powershell:

```
>C:\Directory\Folder1
Folder1 - 01.png
Folder1 - 02.png
Folder1 - 03.jpg
Folder1 - 04.jpg
Folder1 - 05.png
```

So I came up with this simple line:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".jpg" -or $_.Extension -eq ".png"} | rename-item -newname {$_.Directory.Name +" - " + $_.Name}
```

If I have 35 or less files in the folder, I will have the wanted result, but if there is **36 or more** files, I will end up with this:

```
>C:\Directory\Folder1
Folder1 - Folder1 - Folder1 - 01.png
Folder1 - Folder1 - Folder1 - 02.png
Folder1 - Folder1 - Folder1 - 03.jpg
Folder1 - Folder1 - Folder1 - 04.jpg
Folder1 - Folder1 - Folder1 - 05.png
```

The loop stops when the file's name exceeds 248 characters.

Any ideas why it's looping?

EDIT:
As proposed, a simple solution is to check if the folder's name is already added to the file's name:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".jpg" -or $_.Extension -eq ".png" -and !$_.Name.StartsWith($_.Directory.Name) } | rename-item -newname {$_.Directory.Name +" - " + $_.Name}
```

But it doesn't tell me why it's looping when there is over 36 files in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem as if the rename looks like a new file to the loop and so it is being processed again.

Try putting in an additional test to the where to stop it looking at any file starting with "Folder 1".

Comment: I changed the code to check if the folder's name has already been added, but I still doesn't understand why this threshold of 36 make it loop.
I will accept it as an answer if nobody come up with an explanation to this bug.

Comment: I think that, if you were to dig deeper, it would probably be due to the size of the data. At some point, the script is probably overflowing an internal (system?) variable size and flushing to disk. At that point, you have "new" entries in the folder that the script duly processes.